# Vector containing a numerical value not being equal to the actual value

Tags: r

I think I am getting crazy.

In the following computations, I need to make sure that my proportions equals 100.

I need

```
sum(res$percBas, res$percInt, res$percTop) == 100
```

R returns FALSE and I have no clue why! They have the same class and the value of the sum is 100 from the data I provided below.
The proportion are calculated as follows:

```
res$percBas = (res$nBas/res$S)*100
res$percTop = (res$nTop/res$S)*100
res$percInt = (res$nInt/res$S)*100
```

Is it because nTop, nBas, nInt are integers? Though the proportions are numeric...

Output stored for now in a list:

```
res = list(S = 43L, L = 252, Z = 5.86046511627907, C = 0.136289886425095, 
G = 6.81081081081081, GenSD = 1.10870900316409, V = 6.14634146341463, 
VulSD = 0.87450656075054, path = 3, dist = 1.41414141414141, 
degc.tot = 0.259353741496599, cloc.tot = 0.502648845059257, 
betc = 0.0103169994284977, MxSim = 0.565777991877899, meanTL = 2.31254748158818, 
maxTL = 3.46153846153846, nBas = 6L, percBas = 13.953488372093, 
nTop = 2L, percTop = 4.65116279069767, nInt = 35L, percInt = 81.3953488372093)
```

Comment: Trying to get floating point numbers to exactly match is a dangerous game. The safer alternative here is `all.equal(sum(res$percBas, res$percInt, res$percTop), 100)`

Comment: [Relevant?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47222009/8245406) More or less the same idea is [this function `zeq`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47221898/8245406).

Comment: @RuiBarradas I think that is exactly what `dplyr::near()` does as well.

Comment: The thing I don't get is why it is "near 100" and not 100 exactly. nTop+nBas+nInt should be equal to S otherwise it means 1 or more species are not included. Which here would be problematic.

Comment: It's floating point precision. Perhaps read on the topic a bit. It's not you - its the computer. In your example, remove the `* 100` from each percent calculation. You see that if you do that they will `== 1`. When you multiple by 100, you lose a minuscule amount of precision out to the 16th decimal place, as you can see in my answer. This is the case in this example, but might not always be.

Answer (score 3):

It is a numeric precision thing.

```r
> options(digits= 16)
> sum(res$percBas, res$percInt, res$percTop)
[1] 99.99999999999997
```

So you would need to round the sum and then check for equality.

Comment: I thought of that but since the sum of top+int+bas equals S, why wouldn't it be 100% in the proportion? If the proportions are not equal to 100 that means there is a species missing somewhere.