# R floating point issues for conditional inexing

Tags: r, floating-point

I have an issue where I was trying to do some conditional indexing across a data frame but things weren't quite working out as I expected. For example I was looking for all rows where `lat == -26.34`.

```
> t.df[t.df$lat == -26.34,]   
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

But I know for a fact that number is in the data frame...

```
> t.df$lat[4140]
[1] -26.34
```

And even more strange...

```
> t.df$lat[4140] == -26.34
[1] FALSE
```

Upon further investigation it turns out the numbers I'm working with have different floating point values. Hence why `-26.34 == -26.34` evaluates `FALSE`.

```
> sprintf("%.30f", t.df$lat[4140])
[1] "-26.339999999999996305177774047479"
> sprintf("%.30f", -26.34)
[1] "-26.340000000000003410605131648481"
```

I understand why this can happen ([see here](https://floating-point-gui.de/basic/)) but what I want to know is the following:

1. How can I avoid this?
2. How can I do indexing such as `t.df[t.df$lat == -26.34,]` successfully when this issue does crop up?

Comment: See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47222009/8245406). Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50569202/8245406).

Comment: Thanks @Rui and also Henrik. Those are very useful posts. I will mark this question as a duplicate.